# How to prove convexity of this function?

Tags: convex-optimization

How to prove convexity of this function?I want to prove the convexity of the following function:

$f(\gamma)=$\begin{equation}        \begin{aligned}            log(\sum^{n+1}_{i=1} i^{-\gamma})-log(\sum^{n}_{i=1} i^{-\gamma})        \end{aligned}        \end{equation}

I've tried to calculate the second deriviate, but it's really complicate and hard to tell    whether it's positive or not.

Can anyone help me with that? Thank you very much.

Comment: Can you provide some context? Where does that function come from?

Comment: @MartinR  At first I want to prove the convexity of the function    \begin{equation}        \begin{aligned}            log(\sum^{n+1}_{i=1} i^{-\gamma})-log(\sum^{n}_{i=1} i^{-\gamma})        \end{aligned}        \end{equation}    for any given n. I'm still not sure whether this is correct. But I have    checked $n\le 1500$.    And let $c_i=\frac {n+1} {k}$, I got the function in the question. At     first I think that it's true for arbitrary $c_i$. But as you said, this is wrong.    So can you help me with the original function? Thanks again for your time.